# How long is a movie?

Tags: dialogue, production

Is there a length of time in which a movie is not a movie?
Is there point where the movie is to long to be a movie? I am looking for some kind of time table in which movies are classified.

Comment: This questions seems quite a bit too fuzzy. Can you provide a little bit more elaboration what you're after here?

Answer (score 5):

It's somewhat a matter of opinion.  However, the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences defines a short movie as having a running time of [40 minutes or less](https://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/90aa_short_films.pdf) (pdf).

By their definition a "full" feature length movie has to be more than 40 minutes.

I am not aware of any upper limit, there are movies such as Andy Warhol's [Empire (1965)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0196530/) which is over 8 hours long and was shown in movie theaters. If that seems too much like an art installation rather than a feature film, there are a number of mainstream movies that are far longer than most made today:

- [Gone with the Wind](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031381/) (3hr 58 minutes)
- [Once Upon a Time in America](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087843/) (3hr 49 minutes)
- [Lawrence of Arabia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056172/) (3hr 36 minutes)

Comment: At the other end of the scale, Red Cliff ran 4h50, & Andy Warhol managed 25h for **** though idk anyone who watched it all ;)